# change the collide zone of the QGraphicPixmapItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a image below which size is 1024x82, but i want to set the collide zone a bit smaller for example the red rectangle zone is exactly the zone i want.
Is it possible to do that?

[image: Origin image]

[image: example of my question]

Comment: Yep, just reimplement `shape()` for your item.

Comment: @dtech ok i'll try it ^ ^